# What does this route map modification mean?

Tags: networking, route, static-routes

I've inherited administration duties for a firewall/gateway server, and I'm trying to understand what a particular static route setup in rc.local means:

```
...
route add 123.123.123.123/30 10.10.3.14
route add 123.123.123.123/32 10.10.3.13
...
```

Obviously, the IP addresses have been changed to protect the innocent.

What does this mean, and why is it routed this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means packets for 123.123.123.120-122 will go via 10.10.3.14 and packets for 123.123.123.123 will go via 10.10.3.13.

- Since the advent of CIDR, netmasks indicate the length of the prefix - technically any IP in the network can be used, but by convention the non-masked bits are set to 0, which is why 'network addresses' are always on even numbers.
- Most specific wins - /32 is more specific (longer) than /30, so it takes precedence over the /30.

Answer (score 0):

Are the "123.123.123.123" addresses really the exact same in the setup you are debugging - or are they slightly different?

Assuming they are different - the first line means that anything in the network defined by 123.123.123.123/30 should be forwarded to 10.10.3.14.
The second line means the specific IP address 123.123.123.123 should be forwarded to 10.10.3.13.

As to why - we'd need more context.

- Can you tell me the last octet (the last .123) specifically - what exactly is it in your situation.  Having two of htem the same with two different netmasks is a bit weird, and could mean a couple of different things....

Comment: They're the same, exactly.

Comment: What context might you need to answer these questions? And what does it mean when the two IPs are the same?

Answer (score 0):

First line: packets to hosts at `123.123.123.123/30` are routed via `10.10.3.14`, except (second line) for packets to `123.123.123.123/32`, which are routed via `10.10.3.13`.

However, I suspect a anonymization error, if you really define a /30 network, the first address (same ip/32) is the "network"-address, which doesn't really get packets. It could also be, that someone tries to route a slice out of a bigger subnet differently, but it smells funny...

Comment: it's not the network-address it's the broadcast address... odd numbers are as far as I know never net addresses. A better notation for the network would be 123.123.123.120/30.

Comment: The IP addresses were chosen for obfuscation purposes, I didn't realize that the oddness/evenness would be such a red herring to people.